# Convert Dataframe of itemsets to asymmetric binary attribute

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of itemsets and I want to change to asymmetric binary attributes for each item
[image]

I have managed to do this but with a very lengthy process; creating a new list for each row in df and iterating through to check for each items.

```
list1= list(shopping.loc[0])
list2= list(shopping.loc[1])
list3= list(shopping.loc[2])
list4= list(shopping.loc[3])
list5= list(shopping.loc[4])
list6= list(shopping.loc[5])
list7= list(shopping.loc[6])
list8= list(shopping.loc[7])

list9= list(shopping.loc[8])
list10= list(shopping.loc[9])

ref= ['Milk', 'Burgers', 'Buns', 'Ketchup', 'Coals', 'Beer']

def item_in_list(shop, ref):
    there= []
    for item in ref:
        if item in shop: there.append(1)
        else: there.append(0)
    return there

nl1 = item_in_list(list1, ref)
nl2 = item_in_list(list2, ref)
nl3 = item_in_list(list3, ref)
nl4 = item_in_list(list4, ref)
nl5 = item_in_list(list5, ref)
nl6 = item_in_list(list6, ref)
nl7 = item_in_list(list7, ref)
nl8 = item_in_list(list8, ref)
nl9 = item_in_list(list9, ref)
nl10 = item_in_list(list10, ref)

shop_bin= pd.DataFrame(np.array([nl1, nl2, nl3, nl4, nl5, nl6, nl7, nl8, nl9, nl10 ]),
                   columns=['Milk', 'Burgers', 'Buns', 'Ketchup', 'Coals', 'Beer'])
```

And then combining these lists into a new df to produce the df below

[End Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djyQx.png)

There must be a better way to do this to get to same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use:

```
#assert len(ref) == shopping.shape[1]
shop_bin = shopping.eq(ref, axis=1).astype(int).set_axis(ref, axis=1)
```